# How to replace \r\n with " " in R

Tags: r

I read a HTML file into R and remove all HTML files based on previous answers. However, there is always \r\n inside the text. How can I replace them with " "? Your inputs will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a small, reproducible example with sample input data and expected output that closely resembles your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
> x <- 'abc\r\n123\r\n'
> gsub('[\n\r]',' ',x)
[1] "abc 123 "
```

Comment: Maybe `gsub('[\n\r]',' ',x)` might be better? Or `gsub('\r\n', ' ', x)`

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes, definitely. I wrote this answer without testing it.

Comment: My file is data.frame. The gsub did not work. Thanks.

Comment: @lucyh Then please read about how to supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: None of these seems to work: Any suggestions? `> x <- "\\nDécor is fun"
> gsub('[\\n]',' ',x)
[1] "  Décor is fu "
> gsub('[\n\r]',' ',x)
[1] "\\nDécor is fun"`

Comment: Ended up using a hacky solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384784/how-to-replace-r-n-characters-in-a-text-string-specifically-in-r     `> x <- "\\nDécor is fun"
> gsub('__n', '', gsub('[\\\\]', '__', x))
[1] "Décor is fun"`

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me; I had to use:

```
> x <- 'abc\r\n123\r\n'
> gsub('[\r\n][\r\n]',' ',x,perl=TRUE)
[1] "abc 123 "
```